# Google 'Big Table' like data in SQL? How to design DB?

Tags: sql

I need to create a database that, among other things, lets people choose 1 - N zip codes in the US.

Intuitively it seems best to make users a row and zip codes columns.

The problem I am having is that is like 42k columns. Which I am confident is outside most SQL DBs upper bound on columns.

I could have separate tables for each state. And then would have like 500-5K columns / table?

I mean that is doable, but the whole thing just seems a little ridiculous.

All thoughts, critiques, etc. are appreciated.

Also, any know the best place to get a list of zip codes (maybe broken down by state?)? Googling yielded some dated stuff. And so far I have USPS APIs for live verification. But I just need a static list.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: But why not a table with a row for each zip code?

Comment: Don't make it columns, make it rows. And the USPS API would probably be the best place to get the list.

Comment: Also, what version of SQL?

Comment: I don't think the zip codes can be rows because I would then have to modify the table by adding new columns each time I get a new user...

Comment: I haven't settled on a version of SQL.  Probably PSQL?  IDK, its a Django site.

Comment: *"Intuitively it seems best to make users a row and zip codes columns"* - definitely **not**. The ZIP codes need to go into rows. And no, you don't have to add new columns when you add a new user. You simply add rows. That's a textbook example of a many-to-many relationship in relational modelling

Answer (score 0):

In any database -- including BigQuery -- your description suggests a table `UserZips` with one row per `UserId` and `ZipCode`.

Bigquery does not require such a structure.  It supports arrays within a row, so you can have an array of the zip codes that a user chooses.

It also supports records within a row, so you can  have an array of records.  Each record could have a zip code and other information.

In many databases, including BigQuery, you might find a JSON object to be the appropriate representation.

Nonetheless, what first comes to mind is a table with a column for the user and zip code.

Comment: Note that Postgres also supports (very efficiently) arrays and records and arrays of records in rows.

Comment: Thank you.  What first comes to mind to me is a UserZip - table (user = PK, LinkedList-zips).

Comment: This is great, about arrays and records, what about linked lists?  I guess the move would just be to allocate the array = num zip codes, that way I don't have to keep reallocating as preferences change?

Comment: @user: even if Postgres offers all that I would **not** recommend doing it. Go for a normalized model first. Only de-normalize if you absolutely have to.

Comment: And to add to what @a_horse_with_no_name, I honestly can't think of a good reason to not go with the normalized approach. You would be saving yourself _tons_ of headaches in the long run. Don't let a desired solution drive your problem. You will be a much happier camper in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

A structure like this would allow you to add as many zip codes as needed and link as many zips as you needed to as many users as you have.

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=6d1c3a41cb439d17f4def51a672766e1

```
CREATE TABLE zipCodes ( 
   zipID int identity
  , zipcode varchar(5) NOT NULL
  , zipPlusFour varchar(4) DEFAULT '0000' 
  , CONSTRAINT PK_zipID PRIMARY KEY (zipID)
) ;

CREATE TABLE users (
  userID int identity
  , username nvarchar(20) NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT PK_userID PRIMARY KEY (userID)
) ;

CREATE TABLE xref_users_zips (
  userID int NOT NULL
  , zipID int NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT FK_userID FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users(userID)
  , CONSTRAINT FK_zipID FOREIGN KEY (zipID) REFERENCES zipCodes(zipID)
) ;

INSERT INTO zipCodes (zipcode) 
VALUES ('00501'), ('00544'), ('00601')
;

INSERT INTO users (username)
  VALUES ('johndoe'),('robertbuilder'),('zaphodbeeblebrox')
;

INSERT INTO xref_users_zips (userID, zipID)
VALUES (1,1), (2,2), (3,3)
;

SELECT * 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN xref_users_zips xuz ON u.userID = xuz.userID
INNER JOIN zipcodes z ON xuz.zipID = z.zipID
```

Comment: The above is T-SQL. For Postgres, the syntax will be a little different.

Comment: I would also consider allowing more than just US zips. You'd have to change quite a bit in your zips table if some day down the road you added Canadian addresses. Just a thought. :-)

Comment: Conversion to Postgres was easier than I thought. Just change the "int identity" columns to "serial" columns and change the nvarchar() type to varchar() type.   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/08421/1

Comment: No worries on the syntax.  Thanks for the reply.  This is what most people have been saying and I think I will end up going with.